# Disabled menuitem let show the sub menuitems

Tags: c#, winforms

In my program, with the userright variable either i enable or disable a menuitem as shown on the picture below:

[image]

When I click on disabled menuitem the submenuitems are not displayed. But When I click first on a menuitem not disabled such as Raporlar or others and then after i click on disabled menu item the submenuitems under this are displayed as below

[image]

Is this a bug of NET3.5 or I miss something subtile ?

Here is the code where I disable those submenuitems.

```
    private void CheckUserRights(bool stat)
    {
        admin.Enabled = stat;
        admin_pnl.Enabled = stat;
        backup_data.Enabled = stat;
        restore_data.Enabled = stat;
        year_end.Enabled = stat;
        copy_schema.Enabled = stat;
        create_schemas.Enabled = stat;
        clear_log.Enabled = stat;
        base_parity.Enabled = stat;
        dosya_ctrl.Enabled = stat;
    }
```